# Vagrant setup to get PostgreSQL to use UTF8 encoding by default?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, postgis, vagrant

I'm trying to get a VM set up in Vagrant so that when the machine comes up PostgreSQL is running and using an encoding of UTF8, but it's LATIN1 every time, no matter what I do.

The instructions on this page: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-install-postgis-and-geodjango-on-ubuntu/ make it look so simple, but that's just not working. I see the same instructions on site after site, but they don't work!

Comment: Depends on your operating system, package, versions, ...

Answer (score 2):

I just put an answer to this issue here: [Chef ENV settings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161816/chef-env-settings-not-working/19982813#19982813) hope helps with your issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and spent a bit of wresting and tweaking to get it right.  Got the hack from this

[Force Postgres to install with UTF8 encoding, not LATIN1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815440/force-postgres-to-install-with-utf8-encoding-not-latin1)

And put it in my vagrant file, along with some other tweaks, perhaps some will find this useful

https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/0770dba1ae56efed681e6acdd0864d09